# Updating Label under loop in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop

I have the below code, which will show text "*Welcome!*" on executing the code. And then when you click on <kbd>Label</kbd> it will show text "*Test **#***", where # is the number of loop. And then when you click on <kbd>Label1</kbd> it will show text "*Testing*" (stopping the loop).

Code:-

```
m_root = Tk()
m_root.wm_state('zoomed')
m_frame = Frame(m_root)
m_display = Label(m_frame)
labels = []
label = Label(m_root,text="Welcome!") #set your text
label.pack()
labels.append(label)


def label():
    global label_loop
    label_loop = 0
    while label_loop != 1:
        for txt in labels:
            txt.destroy()

        label = Label(m_root,text="Test " + str(label_loop)) #set your text
        label.pack()
        labels.append(label)
        label_loop += 2
        m_display.update()
        time.sleep(1)



def label1():
    global label_loop
    label_loop = 1

    for txt in labels:
        txt.destroy()

    label1 = Label(m_root,text="Testing") #set your text
    label1.pack()
    labels.append(label1)

m_display.pack()
m_frame.pack()
m_display.update()
m_menubar = Menu(m_root)
m_menubar.add_command(label="Label", command=label)
m_menubar.add_command(label="Label1", command=label1)
m_root.config(menu=m_menubar)
m_root.mainloop()
```

Is this the good code to stop loop, or having dynamic labels? Or is there any more cool/smart/short version?

Comment: The loop is iterating only once. And I cannot comprehend your question. Please tell what you really want to do.

Comment: what happens after `"Testing"` is done?

Answer (score 0):

`label_loop` is a complex implementation of a simple boolean state, and hard to understand. You might do this:

```
def label():
    global keep_looping
    keep_looping = True
    loop_count = 0
    while keep_looping:
        for txt in labels:
            txt.destroy()

        label = Label(m_root,text="Test " + str(loop_count))
        label.pack()
        labels.append(label)
        loop_count = loop_count + 1
        m_display.update()
        time.sleep(1)

    for txt in labels:
        txt.destroy()
    label1 = Label(m_root,text="Testing")
    label1.pack()
    labels.append(label1)
    m_display.update()

def label1():
    global keep_looping
    keep_looping = False
```

Note how the `label1` function does *not* set the text to "Testing": there is period of time after the `label1` function sets the `keep_looping` flag to false and when the loop actually stops. The text "Testing" should not appear until the loop has actually stopped.

Also, you'll want to add logic to deal with attempting to execute the `label` function more than once. Right now, nothing prevents the user from selecting the 'label' menu twice in a row: there can be multiple loops running.

Also, deal with the 'close' button: if you click 'close' while the loop is running, you get a nasty exception.